# Почему происходит ошибка "conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier oktell"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT [Id], @text
FROM [dbo].[A_Stat_Connections_1x1]
where [IdChain] = @IdChain
```

`idChain` это поле типа `uniqueidentifier` , `@idChain` это переменная в программе которая получает это поле во время выполнения. Данные в нее записываются, я проверял. Если убрать переменную и просто вставить в скобках `'idchain (сам uid цепочки)'`, то все ок, а переменную ставлю, то пишет ошибку:

```
conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier oktell
```

Пробовал `(SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,@id_chain))`, не помогает.

Что можно сделать с этим?

Comment: Весь ли необходимый код Вы привели? Где определения переменных?

Comment: Дело в том, что это делает интерфейс программы. Он устанавливает в нее эти значения без объявлений тут в запросе. Когда я лог вывожу я вижу этот idChain

Comment: и он действительно совпадает с idChain в таблице [dbo].[A_Stat_Connections_1x1]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы строка могла преобразоваться в GUID, она должна иметь вид 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', где 'x' - шестнадцатеричная цифра, а дефисы обязательно присутствуют на своих местах.

Comment: [loc_idchain] ce1e8c4d-0e90-41ee-b8cd-026a45be54e6   вот то что должно записаться, loc_idchain название переменной, @idChain и loc_idchain одно и тоже, я просто присваиваю idchain значение loc_idchain